# Use GND as V- in voltage regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, ground, negative-voltage

For a circuit sensor, I need +15 V/GND/-15 V. My supply voltage is a single +5 V rail from a standard switching PSU. I looked at different voltage regulators and found, besides others, the ITA series from XP Power, specifically the [ITA0515S](https://assets.alliedelec.com/image/upload/v1606391746/Datasheets/88bdf2a8c9c568d3ebbd750aca42741c.pdf).

Can I use +5 V on Pin1, and GND on Pin2, to still get +15 V/-15 V on P4/5?

Ordering a sample and trying it out would take too long. I need to order a fitted PCB for prototyping directly, but I am still unsure when to use V-, when GND, and when Vss.

Answer (score 4):

Does my green and red mark-up on the information on page 1 of the data sheet make things easier to understand: -

[image]

There is galvanic isolation between green and red pins. This means you can choose to leave the two circuits isolated or, connect them. The device won't care.

> *Can I use +5 V on Pin1, and GND on Pin2, to still get +15 V/-15 V on
> P4/5?*

Pins 4 and 6 produce the +15/-15 volt output with respect to pin 5. This leaves you with the option of connecting pin 5 to pin 2 (thus bypassing the isolation) to make +15 volts on pin 6 and -15 volts on pin 4.

But there are other options: -

- Connect pin 4 to pin 2 and get +15 volts from pin 5 and +30 volts from pin 6
- Connect pin 6 to pin 2 and get -15 volts from pin 5 and -30 volts from pin 4

And there are more option if you connect one of the isolated pins to incoming +5 volts. If you connect pin 5 to pin 1 you can produce -10 volts on pin 4 and +20 volts on pin 6.

Comment: That aswers it great, thank you! Deeper background question: how would that VR internally generate probably these voltages? transform it up to 30v and then split it in the middle, like a simple voltage divider?

Comment: It will most likely use a flyback converter. It will naturally provide isolation and can have several secondary windings that can be configured for positive and negative outputs @Sacharon